# Jsoup accessing the HTML select tag

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm new to jsoup and having a bit of trouble with html tag. I need to get value attribute of select list options based on a text they contain. For example:

```
'<select id="list">
<option value="0">First value</option>
<option value="1">Second value</option>
<option value="2">Third value</option>
</select>'
```

Do you have an idea how I can tell jsoup to return the value "1" if it gets a "Second value" as a parameter for a search?

Answer (score 6):

Here's another solution:

```
public String searchAttribute(Element element, String str)
{
    Elements lists = element.select("[id=list]");

    for( Element e : lists )
    {
        Elements result = e.select("option:contains(" + str + ")");

        if( !result.isEmpty() )
        {
            return result.first().attr("value");
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

**Test:**

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html); // html is your listed html / xml
Strign result = searchAttribute(doc, "Second value") // result = 1
```

Answer (score 6):

This may Help You..

```
String demo = "<select id='list'><option value='0'>First value</option><option value='1'>Second value</option><option value='2'>Third value</option></select>";


        Document document = Jsoup.parse(demo);
        Elements options = document.select("select > option");

        for(Element element : options)
        {
            if(element.text().equalsIgnoreCase("second value"))
            {
                System.out.println(element.attr("value"));
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
String searchValue = "Second value";
Elements options = doc.select("#list > option");
String value = "";
for (Element option : options) {
    String text = option.text();
    if (text.equals(searchValue)){
        value = option.attr("value");
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry, there was an extra 's' in 'optionS' line no. 2. Kindly check it now.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest solution is:

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
 String value = doc.select("#list > option:contains(Second value)").val();
```